# How to increase the default size of response in Cosmos DB (Java SDK)

Tags: java, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

As below github says,

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/cosmos-db/nosql/performance-tips-query-sdk.md#tune-the-page-size-1

The default page size is either 100 or 4 MB.
We can override the page size from 100 to any number as given in the above example.

But can we increase the default size from 4MB ?

Comment: Please edit to provide a [mcve], with code/data/errors/etc.

Comment: @DavidMakogon I don't have a proper example/error as I have not got any code or snippet for size part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot increase the limit of 4MB on the response, this is not a client-defined limit.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/concepts-limits#per-request-limits